# Check particular checkbox after paging in kendo grid

Tags: javascript, jquery, checkbox, asp.net-mvc-5, kendo-asp.net-mvc

I have a Kendo grid in which I have one column of checkbox. I'm doing paging, suppose I have 3 pages, I make check some checkboxes (select some row) on first page then go to second page and after checking some checkboxes again I come to first page, but when I come to first page I want all the checkboxes checked which I have checked before paging.
But when I come back to first page it selects all the checkboxes, I'm unable to make check the particular checkbox which I have checked before. Please help me out.

`checkedUserList` is an array of all the Checked row's Id.

```
$('#gridUsersList tbody .chkbox').each(function () {
        var userid = $(this).data("userid");

        for (var i = 0; i < checkedUserList.length; i++) {

            if (userid == checkedUserList[i]) { // && checkedUserList[i] > 0

                // the commented line check all the checkboxes
                //$('#gridUsersList.chkbox').prop('checked', true);

                $(this).find("input[type=checkbox] .chkbox").prop('checked', true);
                break;
            }
        }
 });




    @(Html.Kendo().Grid(Model).Name("gridUsersList")
        .Events(events => events.Change("Grid_OnRowSelect").DataBound("onDataBound_Users"))
   .Columns(columns =>
     {
        columns.Bound(User => User.isChecked)
           .ClientTemplate("<input type='checkbox' id='SelectedClientUsers_#=ID#' class='chkbox' data-userid='#= ID #' />")
            .HeaderTemplate("<input type='checkbox' name='SelectAllClientUsers' id='SelectAllClientUsers' />").Width("20%");

        columns.Bound(User=> User.DisplayName).Title("Name").Width("40%");
        columns.Bound(User=> User.EmailAddress).Title("Email").Width("40%");
    })
```

Comment: You should save in an array what rows you are checking, so when you change pages you still have those values somewhere, I don't see any other option

Comment: Thanks @MarioGarcia ! But I got the solution.